# How to use a variable to declare a new JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, parameters, jcombobox, comboboxmodel

I need to create a new JComboBox, but since I'm using the same JFrame for three different operations, I would need to pass the JComboBox name as a parameter

This is the code I have right now:

```
    comboTipo=("Tienda."+tablaP+"Items");
    tipo = new JComboBox(comboTipo);
```

If I print comboTipo I can read "Tienda.telasItems" or "Tienda.accesoriosItems" or "Tienda.aviosItems". I'm looking to use this text into the combo box declaration so I don't have to create a decision structure

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access variables through strings directly in Java (not without reflection which doesn't make much sense here), you are trying to do something which is not allowed.

You should solve problem with a different approach, for example you could use an array:

```
Object[][] data = new Object[][]{Tienda.telasItems, Tienda.accesoriosItems, Tienda.aviosItems};
JComboBox[] boxes = new JComboBox[3];

for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; ++i)
  boxes[i] = new JComboBox(data[i]);
```

Comment: The problem is that I have telasItems declared in Tienda class
Tienda class calls the class that creates the main window called VentanaPrincipal, and VentanaPrincipal class calls to the specific class Alta where the JComboBox is declared.
Can I use the code you wrote anyways? O should I  try something different?

Comment: @CMM777: so pass the data array or collection, into the GUI class via a setter method. I don't see where you're stuck or why you can't do this. 1+ to Jack for his answer.

Comment: Solved, thanks Jack
I added the object declaration and sent the index number as a parameter
Now the code looks like this:

        Object[][] comboTipo = new Object[][]{Tienda.telasItems, Tienda.accesoriosItems, Tienda.aviosItems};
        tipo = new JComboBox(comboTipo[i]);

Thanks again, and sorry for the dumb question, I'm pretty new to Java